# Azure manage compute API is failing with InvalidAPIVersion error

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-management, azure-resource-manager, azure-management-api

I am trying to use Azure resource manager and Azure Compute Management APIs to get list of virtual machines in a resource group and all of virtual machine properties. It's failing with InvalidAPIVersion error even though I have updated to latest version. As per the error it expects older version no but i don't see any old library with such a version. Can someone please suggest what am I missing?

VirtualMachineGetResponse vm = m_computeClient.VirtualMachines.Get("/subscriptions/1f94c869-####-####-####-055e8ae15be3/resourceGroups/TestGroup", "TestMachine");

m_computeClint is an object of ComputeManagementClient class in name space Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute

Is this because resource provider is Microsoft.ClassicCompute?

Error message:
InvalidApiVersionParameter: The api-version '2015-05-01-preview' is invalid. The supported versions are '2015-01-01,2014-04-01-preview,2014-04-01,2014-01-01,2013-03-01,2014-02-26,2014-04'.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the resource group management api, you're definitely going to get an invalidapiversionparameter using ClassicCompute. The resource management compute provider is "Microsoft.Compute"; ClassicCompute exists only to view VMs that were already created using the service management API.

Right now, you should keep the two APIs and resources separate. Did you create the VM using the preview portal (portal.azure.com) or using PowerShell? If the former, it has almost (but not quite) converted over to using the resource management api. Try following these steps: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-template-deploy/.

Hope that helps.